# Joomla Virtuemart - Reduce number of order confirmation emails

Tags: joomla, virtuemart

Virtuemart generates too many emails during the ordering process, i.e. sends a "pending" status email before the user has completed checkout and two status "confirmed" emails - one after submitting credit card form and another after clicking the subsequent "Next" button.

I have not found a conclusive thread that deals with this once and for all.
The only email we need is after final Confirmation from the merchant.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Actually, I've a feeling that one or more of the emails are originating from the credit card gateway plugin for VirtueMart. I'm investigating and will update.

Comment: That's definitely not VM sending those. VM does not send any emails to the user until they click the confirm order button and the order is completed.

Answer (score 0):

Like Brent wrote above, VirtueMart sends the "order confirmation" email, when the customer click the confirm order button. This is done when order is actually in "pending" status, before payment is completed. The real confirmed order is sent by VM when the payment module changes the order status to confirm, after payment completes.

You can control all standard emails (user registration, order confirmation, admin order confirmation, status changed, download ID) and many others with extensions like [Emails manager](http://www.interamind.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=76&Itemid=84) and [Emails manager pro](http://www.interamind.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=118%3avm-emails-manager-pro&catid=34&Itemid=99)